# How do I build a project with qmake-qt4?

Tags: 11.10, compiling, qt, makefile

I'm new user of Ubuntu, so excuse me if my question is very obvious.

I have a 32-bit Ubuntu 11.10 installed in VirtualBox, and I want to build a project using `qmake-qt4`, the problem is that I don't have any knowledge about that, I've searched in google but what I found is how to use a project file to generate another project file and a Makefile, however I have all of this (Makefile, .pro file) in the project package that I've dowloaded, and the result that I got by typing directly `make` command is as follows:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `first'
```

and if i use `qmake-qt4 -project, qmake-qt4, make`:

```
/usr/bin/qmake-qt4 -o Makefile GATE_PET_2_STIR.pro
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -Iinclude/qwt-6.0.2 -Iinclude/root -IViewer -I. -I. -o viewer.o Viewer/viewer.cpp
In file included from Viewer/viewer.cpp:1:0:
Viewer/viewer.h:101:42: error: ‘Daq_Project’ has not been declared
Viewer/viewer.h:103:17: error: ‘Daq_Project’ has not been declared
Viewer/viewer.cpp:22:33: error: ‘Daq_Project’ has not been declared
Viewer/viewer.cpp:22:1: warning: unused parameter ‘_daq_project’ [-Wunused-parameter]
Viewer/viewer.cpp: In member function ‘void Viewer::on_listWidget_clicked(const QModelIndex&)’:
Viewer/viewer.cpp:74:9: error: ‘pr_data’ was not declared in this scope
Viewer/viewer.cpp:74:19: error: ‘daq_project’ was not declared in this scope
Viewer/viewer.cpp: In member function ‘void Viewer::on_listWidget_2_clicked(const QModelIndex&)’:
Viewer/viewer.cpp:120:5: error: ‘Data_module’ was not declared in this scope
Viewer/viewer.cpp:120:18: error: ‘pr_data’ was not declared in this scope
Viewer/viewer.cpp:124:19: error: ‘daq_project’ was not declared in this scope
Viewer/viewer.cpp: At global scope:
Viewer/viewer.cpp:160:6: warning: unused parameter ‘index’ [-Wunused-parameter]
Viewer/viewer.cpp: In member function ‘void Viewer::on_listWidget_3_clicked(const QModelIndex&)’:
Viewer/viewer.cpp:169:5: error: ‘Data_module’ was not declared in this scope
Viewer/viewer.cpp:169:18: error: ‘pr_data’ was not declared in this scope
Viewer/viewer.cpp:173:19: error: ‘daq_project’ was not declared in this scope
Viewer/viewer.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Viewer::closeEvent(QCloseEvent*)’:
Viewer/viewer.cpp:217:23: error: ‘daq_project’ was not declared in this scope
Viewer/viewer.cpp: At global scope:
Viewer/viewer.cpp:215:6: warning: unused parameter ‘event’ [-Wunused-parameter]
make: *** [viewer.o] Error 1
```

What should I do to fix the errors?

Answer (score 0):

First, restore the code back to the way it was before.  When you ran `qmake-qt4 -project` you stomped all over the previous (and likely correct) `.pro`.

Once you are back to the start, navigate to the directory containing the .pro and type `qmake-qt4`.  That will generate a `Makefile` based on the characteristics in the .pro.  When it finishes, run `make`.  This should build the entire project (assuming you already have the [qt4 build dependencies](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/requirements-x11.html) installed).  If not, [download the Qt 4 source](https://qt-project.org/downloads) and follow [these instructions](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-x11.html).